# How to allow a user "the option" to create own URL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Using mod_rewrite to use a $_GET['variable'] to grab info / pages is easy enough.  How do you give a user the option to do this.  For example: There URL is blah.com/user?id=74378 by default.  Now they can manually create there own URL if available.  How is this done?  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could maintain a table with the list of urls used. This is to check and warn the user if url is unavailable. Then, if the user tries `blah.com/user/myspecialurl` the htaccess should call `blah.com/user?url=myspecialurl`. Then use the table to find the userid and get the contents using the GET variable.

All this is under the assumption that you have a fixed format/restrictions for the url

Comment: Right, simple enough.  So, along with the "if_available_url" table I could add a URL column in the "users" table, set empty by default, then UPDATE it if the user specifies a URL.  In the PHP script I can create an if / else on whether or not to query if the new URL if it's set.  Otherwise it would default to if user_id is set.

Comment: As with any project, you'll need to be careful with your database schema. Depending on the kind of details you'd need from the user table or the url table, you could directly use the `user` table, or add a `userid` field to the `if_url_available` table. Anyway, the schema is something which will be very specific to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The first part, anything, on this page will help where anything = user defined string and u process that string as a GET variable on a fixed page.

http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting-2/

Answer (score 0):

use php module mod_rewrite, and rules in htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and in index.php:

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 'index';
// filter var $page
// ..
// then include needed page
include './pages/'.$page;
// or get content from sql
sql(..WHERE page = $page..)
```